# Checking optional function argument

Tags: arguments, conditionals, boolean

If I have an optional function argument, how can I determine if name has been supplied.  And if it has been supplied, how can I test its validity (not nil or not empty string).

```lisp
    (defun myfunc (&optional name)
      "DOCSTRING"
      (if name
          (do-this)
        (do-that)))
```

Does the `if` statement only check for `name` being `nil`?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the `if` statement only check for [its first arg] being `nil`?

*Yes.*

And you can just *ask Emacs*: **`C-h f if`**.

> `if` is a special form in `C source code`.
>
> `(if COND THEN ELSE...)`
>
> **If `COND` yields non-`nil`**, do `THEN`, else do `ELSE`...
>
> Returns the value of `THEN` or the value of the last of the `ELSE`'s.
>
> `THEN` must be one expression, but `ELSE`... can be zero or more expressions.
>
> If `COND` yields `nil`, and there are no `ELSE`'s, the value is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

`if` switches on `nil` or non-nil so something like

```
(if (and name (not string-empty-p name))
    (do-this)
  (do-that))
```

will do the job.